# fstrim does not trim swap

Tags: linux, encryption, swap, cryptsetup, trim

I have set up an encrypted swap partition following [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Swap_encryption). My `/etc/crypttab` is set up like this (note the `discard` option on swap):

```
rootfs UUID=<UUID_root> none luks,discard
swap UUID=<UUID_swap> /dev/urandom swap,offset=2048,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=512,discard
```

I also have `allow_discards=1` in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`. However, when I do a manual trim, the swap doesn't trim:

```
#sudo /sbin/fstrim -av
/media/win: 670.4 GiB (719872700416 bytes) trimmed
/boot/efi: 221.8 MiB (232525824 bytes) trimmed
/boot: 291 MiB (305152000 bytes) trimmed
/: 221.7 GiB (237996343296 bytes) trimmed
```

how do I make it trim?

---

On a related note, why is `/media/win` being trimmed? This is a NTFS partition on a hard drive (not SSD) automounted by Linux so why is TRIM enabled on a hard drive? In fact, when I print `lsblk -D`, I have `/dev/sda` (my HDD) showing non-zero values for DISC_GRAN and DISC_MAX, indicating that TRIM is enabled. Why is that?

Comment: How can you trim swap? There are no files on it to be deleted, so no blocks that should be marked for cleanup via TRIM.

Comment: Swap partition can be trimmed, there is a ```swapon -d``` discard option for swap. Check ```man swapon``` for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently because swap is not considered as a normal filesystem, it will not be trimmed when `fstrim` is run manually. But it appears that the Linux kernel does the trimming for the swap when it is mounted automatically when the underlying device supports the operation. This is referenced in the [Fedora project docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/newmds-ssdtuning.html):

> The Linux swap code will issue TRIM commands to TRIM-enabled devices, and there is no option to control this behaviour.

One can also see it in the kernel code itself [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/mm/swapfile.c?id=refs/tags/v3.12.5#n2507). So I am not sure how it interacts with encryption but I assume that swap trimming doesn't require any additional configuration (eg in `fstab`) as long as `/etc/crypttab` and `lvm.conf` are set up as in the question above which enables trimming on the LUKS and LVM levels.